# How to create a web service in C# that takes xml request and returns xml response with user defined XML schema?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

How to create a web service in C# that takes XML request and returns XML response with user defined XML schema?

I want to create a simple HTTP web service with the above requirement.

```
[WebMethod]
public XmlDocument HelloWorld(string xmlRequest)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(xmlRequest);

            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(sb.ToString());
            // do function
            //.....

            return xmlDocument;
        }
```

Comment: I have pasted the things what I tried in the main post. Is it not possible to use XMLDocument parameter instead of primitive type string?

Answer (score 1):

You should re-write it like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string HelloWorld(string xmlRequest)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.LoadXml(xmlRequest);
    // do function
    //.....
    return xmlDocument.OuterXml;
}
```

The `StringBuilder` is unnecessary and, while it is possible to pass the whole `XmlDocument` object, I would strongly recommend against it.  All you should be doing is transferring the actual XML text as a string, not the serialized object.

Comment: But the returned string looks awkward if the return type is string as it may look like this,

<string><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><People><Person Name="Nick" /><Person Name="Nick" /></People></string>

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that.  The web service must convert the result to a SOAP message which must specify the type of the return value (string).  But, when you consume the web service as a client, all the SOAP formatting will be stripped off for you by the client's proxy objects.

Comment: yes, but I am not using SOAP client, I have to use http post to consume web service.

Comment: If you are calling a method on a web service, then you must be a SOAP client.  If you aren't using any already-written-and-provided SOAP client library, then you must re-invent the wheel and perform all the SOAP formatting/unformatting yourself.  If you must do so, you may find the SoapFormatter class very helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.soap.soapformatter.aspx

Comment: Why are you not using the built-in web references functionality of Visual Studio to automatically generate the client code for you?

Comment: Because the client code is return in PHP and web service written in C#.

Comment: Then you need to read up on how to write a SOAP client in PHP.  Perhaps it has some built-in abilities to as well.  I'm not very familiar with PHP.  However, what you are doing on the server side is correct (returning it as string).  If you are having trouble writing a proper SOAP client in PHP, perhaps you should ask that as another question under the PHP tag.